# Why is this for loop skipping the second part sometimes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is part of a minimax function that I'm trying to write for tic tac toe. Specifically, this is part of the "maxi" function that the max player calls, which calls mini, which calls maxi, etc. The program is not finding the optimal way of playing. When I run the debugger, sometimes it runs through the whole for loop, and other times, after calling mini on the third line, it will go back to the first line for no reason. Is there some syntactic reason I missed?

```
    for i in acts:
        res = result(board, i)
        minboard = mini(res, alpha, beta)
        if utility(minboard) > maxv:
            maxv = utility(minboard)
            x = i
        if maxv > alpha:
            alpha = maxv
        if beta <= alpha:
            break
```

Comment: Probably because none of the `if` conditions are True, so it skips to the next iteration.

Comment: A bit more context would help. You say this is part of a function. What function? Also, does `mimi` call this very function? That would `teleport` the stack to the previous line, but it's hard to say without the extra details.

Comment: @AnkurAnkan It normally goes to the if statement and skips over the indented part if False

Comment: @doctorlove yes this is part of the maxi function. mini would call this function again unless the terminal state of the game is reached. But since I'm stepping over the mini call, shouldn't it still go to the if statement?

Comment: There may also be a need to 'reset' variables (maxv? alpha?) before each iteration, or refresh board state somehow, which you are forgetting. Is maxv and alpha meant to be carried forward and compared independently at each iteration, or should this depend on the utility itself?

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully aware of how the mini and utility functions work but my gut feeling is that the loop stops as none of your if conditions are met. The usual structure would be, if, elif, else, not just 3 if statements.

```
for i in acts:
    res = result(board, i)
    minboard = mini(res, alpha, beta)
    if utility(minboard) > maxv:
        maxv = utility(minboard)
        x = i
    elif maxv > alpha:
        alpha = maxv
    else:
        break
```